# Can someone Explain Why This While Statement Has to be AND

Tags: java, while-loop, boolean-logic

So basically I am having some trouble understanding the logic that is not allowing this statement to use "OR" but to work perfectly using "AND". By my logic saying equals Y or y or N or n, should work. But if I use this its an infinite loop. The code block can be seen below;

```
      response = "empty";
      while (!response.equals("Y") && !response.equals("y") && !response.equals("N") && !response.equals("n"))
      {
          response = stdin.next();
          if (!response.equals("Y") && !response.equals("y") && !response.equals("N") && !response.equals("n")) {
              System.out.println("Try again, you're still in the loop!");
          }
          else {
              System.out.println("Congratulations you're out the loop!");
          }

      }
  }
```

Could anyone explain to me the logical reason that || cannot be using but && works perfectly. The rest of the code (scanner etc are above but I havent included them as they are not relevant).
Thanks!

Comment: You might want to use `equalsIgnoreCase()`.

Comment: let me introduce [`String.equalsIgnoreCase(String s)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29). It will tidy things up a bit for you.

Comment: Your if statements don't make sense. You are in the loop regardless.

Comment: You will want to read up and learn to use Venn diagrams as they are most useful for trying to understand boolean algebra.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Or truth tables.

Comment: @staticx: yep, I guess it depends on how you best understand these things. For me, it's all visual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with or :

```
while (!(response.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") || response.equalsIgnoreCase("N")))
```

Since

```
(!A && !B && !C) is equivalent to !(A || B || C)
```

It's called [De Morgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

In addition, it would be better to have the condition in only one place :

```
response = stdin.next();
while (!(response.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") || response.equalsIgnoreCase("N")))
{
    System.out.println("Try again, you're still in the loop!");
    response = stdin.next();
}
System.out.println("Congratulations you're out of the loop!");
```

Comment: "DeMorgan's Law" for reference.

Comment: It fixes the math part, but doesn't explain why his case was not working, which is mostly the question

Comment: You could improve this with `equalsIgnoreCase()`.

Comment: Yea, when I first typed it out I did use equalsIgnoreCase, I think I ended up changing it when I couldnt get it to work, must have had the braces wrong and coincidentally finally got it working when I changed it round with the && operators =/. Also thanks for that information about De Morgan's Law, very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

It is because you want the response not to Y, nor y nor N nor n.

Doing OR `||` would crash the logic has if you are Y you ain't y and therefore OR would return true

`||` would make the statement be true at all time.

With X

True since it would not be Y, nor y, nor N, nor N 
So `True or True` or `True` or `True == True`

If you put any of the condition (Y, y, n, N) it would give 
True OR true  OR true OR false (in various order)  == true

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot you can do to improve this code.  Consider

```
response = stdin.next();
while (!response.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || !response.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
{
   System.out.println("Try again, you're still in the loop!");
   response = stdin.next();                
}
System.out.println("Congratulations you're out the loop!");
```

@Eran's answer explains why your logic is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`&&`  Called Logical AND operator. If both the operands are non-zero, then the condition becomes true.

`||` Called Logical OR Operator. If any of the two operands are non-zero, then the condition becomes true.

[image]